# Product of Digits

Tags: code-golf, math

For a given positive integer number N, write a complete program to find the minimal natural M such that the product of digits of M is equal N. N is less than 1,000,000,000. If no M exists, print -1. Your code should not take more than 10 secs for any case.

```
Sample Inputs
1
3
15
10 
123456789
32
432
1296

Sample Outputs
1
3
35
25
-1
48
689
2899
```

Comment: `1` giving `1` is an important test case.

Comment: You should add more complex cases, like the three I've used below: 32, 432, 1296.  Unless you leave that as an exercise for the coder.

Comment: @s-mark 26, eh. Smallest Number.

Comment: I believe we should also test the obvious 387420489 (9^9) and 1000000000 for fun.

Comment: We should also test for prime numbers in input, e.g. 13.

Comment: Because this is an old question and the OP is inactive, this is just a note for future posts: "10 sec" is unclear according to the current standard (on which machine?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Golfscript, <strike>45 43</strike> 40 chars

```
~9{{1$1$%!{\1$/1$}*}12*(}8*>{];-1}*]$1or
```

Replaces version which didn't group small primes into powers and saves 8 chars while doing so. Note: 12 = floor(9 log 10 / log 5).

Acknowledgements: two characters saved by nicking a trick from @mellamokb; 3 saved with a hint from @Nabb.

Comment: What! You can write Golfscript without testing it? +1, Looks fine, except 123456789, its take more than 1 minute on my machine and I've killed the process. `12345` give me -1, so may be it should work for `123456789` too if I could wait long time enough.

Comment: @S.Mark, thanks. Looks like I can't get away with the naive factorisation algorithm.

Comment: @Peter: Gives wrong answers for more complex cases. 32 -> 22222, should be 48.  432 -> 2222333, should be 689.  1296 -> 22223333, should be 2899.  etc.

Comment: @mellamokb, good point. I think I'll have to rewrite and test.

Comment: Wow, 17 characters less.  I need a better algorithm, lol!

Comment: PS @Whoever voted this down while it was giving wrong results for some numbers, it's fixed now.

Comment: `or` is generally the best way to handle special cases for `0`, `[]`, and `''`. It cuts off 3 characters here.

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript (<strike>84</strike> <strike>78</strike> <strike>76</strike> <strike>74</strike> <strike>72</strike> <strike>70</strike> 68)

```
n=prompt(m="");for(i=9;i-1;)n%i?i--:(m=i+m,n/=i);alert(n-1?-1:m?m:1)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D3WgU/7/

**Edit:** Borrowed input/output idea from other solution, and shorter output logic.

**Edit 2:** Saved 2 chars by removing unneeded braces in `for` loop.

**Edit 3:** Saved 2 chars by rewriting `while` loop as `if` statement with `i++`.

**Edit 4:** Saved 2 chars by moving around and reducing operations on `i`.

**Edit 5:** Convert if statement into ternary format saving 2 more chars.

**Edit 6:** Save 2 chars by moving `i--` into true part of ternary, remove `++i`.

Comment: You have counted characters for just the function. Is this a complete program? Can you execute it here http://www.ideone.com/

Comment: looks like there is similar input for javascript with spidermonkey at ideone he linked - http://www.ideone.com/samples#sample_lang_112

Comment: @fR0DDY: OK, now it's a complete program :)

Comment: I finally reduced mine to 69 characters, but you can do that too now with the same sort of idea and the `prompt` thing.

Comment: `m?m:1` => `m||1`

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, <s>88</s> <s>72</s> <s>78</s> <s>74</s> <s>69</s> 68

```
for(s='',i=2,m=n=prompt();i<m;i++)while(!(n%i)){if(i>9){alert(-1);E()}n/=i;s+=i}alert(s)
```

4 characters longer, but actually an executable script (as opposed to a function).

<s>Edit: Using ideas from the other JavaScript, I can reduce it to this:</s>

```
for(s='',i=9,n=prompt();i>1;i--)for(;!(n%i);n/=i)s=i+s;alert(n-1?-1:s?s:1)
```

<s>**Finally!** A 69-character solution, only uses 1 for loop ;)</s>

```
for(s='',i=9,n=prompt();i>1;n%i?i--:[n/=i,s=i+s]);alert(n-1?-1:s?s:1)
```

Okay, shaved off one comma.

```
for(i=9,n=prompt(s='');i>1;n%i?i--:[n/=i,s=i+s]);alert(n-1?-1:s?s:1)
```

Comment: Same problem as GolfScript solution.  Fails on inputs 32, 432, and 1296.  There's a reason why I start at 9 and go backwards, and concatenate from the right instead of the left.

Comment: Also fails for input 1.  Have to make a special case to handle 1.

Comment: I missed the "minimal" part, changed.

Comment: @minitech: Still doesn't work for input '1'.  lol, our answers are coming out to be almost exactly identical :-)

Comment: Ah, managed to make it 2 characters shorter than yours! :D

Comment: Ah, managed to make it *4* characters *shorter* than *yours*! :P  And beat Perl to boot.

Comment: Ah, managed to make it 1 character shorter than yours!!

Comment: @minitech: Yeah, lol, and that didn't even save any characters.  I think I'll switch it back to `prompt` and `alert`.

Comment: @minitech: You steal my idea, I'll steal yours :)  Now mines 1 character shorter than yours again!! lol!

Comment: When did I steal your `prompt` idea? Edit: Oh, you mean the `for` thing. I didn't steal that, I always thought you had 2 loops!

Comment: Now ours are the same length :)

Answer (score 4):

### awk (<strike>63</strike> <strike>61</strike> <strike>59</strike> <strike>58</strike> 57)

```
{for(i=9;i>1;$1%i?i--:($1/=i)<o=i o);print 1<$1?-1:o?o:1}
```

Comment: We are calling program for one input only. Multiple inputs are given just to check correctness.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl <strike>(75)</strike> (72)

```
$d=shift;map{$m=$_.$m,$d/=$_ until$d%$_}reverse 2..9;print$d-1?-1:$m||1
```

inspired by mellamokb's javascript code; meant to be run with a parameter

Comment: Would it not be shorter if you used stdin instead of a parameter?

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript (<strike>60</strike> 57)

```
~[{9,{)}%{\.@%!},)\;.@@/.9>2$1>&}do])[.])@@{1>},+\9>[-1]@if$
```

```
~{9,{)}%{\.@%!},)\;.@@/.9>2$1>&}do])[.])@@{1>},+$\9>-1@if
```

**Edit**

Ok, I think this version gives correct output for every case now :-)

**Edit 2**

Shaved off 3 chars per @Peter's suggestions.

Comment: The reason I commented above that `1` giving `1` is an important test case is that it's a nasty special case - the only number for which the digit `1` appears in the output. And it breaks your code, I'm afraid.

Comment: It also breaks for numbers divisible by primes greater than 9.

Comment: @Peter: OK, try again.  I think this version works for all test cases now.

Comment: Seems to, yes. You can save one character straight away by removing that first `[` - if you don't have a `[` on the stack when you evaluate a `]` it takes everything on the stack. And you can probably save two characters near the end by not wrapping `-1` in an array and moving the final `$`.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, saved 3 more chars!

Comment: @Peter: I'm completely new to GolfScript, this is about my third program.  What am I doing wrong that I'm wasting so many characters?  When I look at your solutions, you seem to be fond of the {....}#* pattern.  Is that usually a more efficient approach?

Comment: When you can do something as `{stuff}num*` or `{stuff.}do` the first is often shorter. And `bool{stuff}*` is clearly shorter than the equivalent `bool{stuff}{}if`. I think possibly with practice I'm getting better at avoiding `@@` (I wish Golfscript had a rotate-the-other-way operator). I haven't analysed your program in detail, so I'm not sure specifically which parts are costing you characters.

Comment: Blocks are fairly expensive. So `9,{)}%{\.@%!},)\;`, for example, to find the largest single-digit factor of the number on the stack without destroying it, is an obvious target for improvement. Actually the best I've got for this so far is more C-like: loop down. `9{1$1$%!!-}8*`

Comment: I also observe that your solution works for any input. Mine doesn't - hence the `12` in my program. `5 13?` would break it, and I save quite a bit there by using a fixed number of iterations rather than calculating termination conditions.

Comment: Although you can simplify your loop termination condition by a character. `x y 1>&` will be 0 or 1, but you only really care about 0 or non-0, so if y is certain to be positive `x y (*` works equally well.

Comment: `)[.])@@{1>},+$` to take `[d0 d1 d2 ... dn]` to `dn [«dn if >1» d{n-1} ... d1 d0]` also raises some red flags. You're sticking `dn` into a one-element array just to filter it and add it back? Seems like a waste of `[]{}`. In fact you can do better by not removing it in the first place and instead filtering the indices. `.).1=@;@$>` My version of your implementation is now down to 48 chars.

Comment: @Peter: Lol. Do I have to figure it out :)

Comment: @mellamokb, you just have to do some search-and-replace ;) `~{9{1$1$%!!-}8*.@@/.9>2$(*}do].).1=@;@$>\9>-1@if` but you'll learn more by looking at the changes I proposed individually.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell

```
f n=head([m|m<-[1..10^9],product(map(read.return)$show m)==n]++[-1])
```

Comment: Shave off one char by changing `(show m)` to `$show m`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `m<-[1..9^9]`....otherwise it's an infinite list...so `-1` will never occur....correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I don't think it can work within 10secs....

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, 87

```
if(($n="$args")-le1){$n;exit}(-1,-join(9..2|%{for(;!($n%$_)){$_;$n/=$_}}|sort))[$n-eq1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl (68)

```
$x=pop;map{$_-=11;$x/=$_,$@=-$_.$@until$x%$_}1..9;print!$x?-1:$@||1
```

It *seems* like the awesome trick that @mellamokb uses in javascript to avoid the nested loop would translate well to perl but it comes out much more verbose because you cannot use the `foreach` style loop any longer.  It's also a pity that perl does not think `map` is a loop else `redo` would come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

#### scala 106 chars:

```
def p(n:Int,l:Int=9):List[Int]=if(n<=9)List(n)else
if(l<2)List(-1)else
if(n%l==0)l::p(n/l,l)else
p(n,l-1)
```

Test & Invocation:

```
scala> val big=9*9*9*8*8*8*7*7*7*5*3 
big: Int = 1920360960

scala> p(big)                        
res1: List[Int] = List(9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3)
```

Response time: immediately, < 1s on 2Ghz CPU.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>18</strike> <strike>13</strike> 10 bytes

```
×⁵RDP$€io-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9EeNW4NcAlQeNa3JzNf9//@/ibERAA)

**13-byte solution:**

```
×⁵RDP$€iµ’¹¬?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//w5figbVSRFAk4oKsacK14oCZwrnCrD////80MzI)

Explanation with input `N`:

```
×³R              create a range from 1 to N * 100 (replace ³ with ⁵ for a faster execution time)
   DP$           define a function ($) to get the product of the digits of a number,
      €          apply that function to each element in the list,
       iµ        get the index of the input N in the list (or 0 if it's not there), and yeild it as the input to the next link,
         ’¹¬?    conditional: if the answer is 0, then subtract one to make it -1, otherwise, yeild the answer
```

**18-byte solution:**

```
D×/
×⁵RÇ€i
Ç⁾-1¹¬?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l8HR9rsPTHzVuDTrc/qhpTSYXkGrcp2t4aOehNfb///83MTYCAA)

```
D×/        product of digits function, takes input M
D          split M into digits,
 ×/        reduce by multiplication (return product of digits)

×⁵RÇ€i     range / index function
×⁵R        make a range from 1 to N*10,
   Ç€      run the above function on each of the range elements,
     i     get the index of N in the result, or 0 if it's not there

Ç⁾-1¹¬?    main function:
Ç    ¬?    run the line above and check if the answer is null (0)
 ⁾-1       if it is, return "-1",
    ¹      otherwise, return the answer (identity function).
```

The last link is only to replace 0 (Jelly's default falsey value, as all lists are one-indexed) with -1. If you consider 0 an OK falsey value, the program is **8 bytes**.

Comment: Some notes: (1) you use each auxiliary link only once, so there is no reason to make auxiliary link. Just use the `$ƊƲµ`. (2) As the string `-1` and the number `-1` is identical when output, using the number saves 2 bytes. (3) `P` is shorthand for `×/`. (4) Fails for input `3125`.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you so much! I implemented (1), (2), and (3) and they saved 6 bytes! If I changed the ⁵ to a ³, it worked on input 3125 but only after a considerable delay. Do you know if there's a better (and shorter) way, or is my approach (which I know is definitely not the fastest in terms of time-complexity) as good as it will get?

Comment: I think `_¬$` should work over `’¹¬?`

Comment: `o-` is even shorter.

Comment: @dylnan Thank you -- I noticed that because of the `µ` I could just use `_¬` without the `$` which saved 2 bytes! But then I realized with `o-` I could just omit the `µ` entirely and save 3 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby (100)

```
n=gets.to_i;(d=1..9).map{|l|[*d].repeated_combination(l){|a|a.reduce(:*)==n&&(puts a*'';exit)}};p -1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 89 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,u=1,i=9:n<2and(a or 1)or-(i<2)or n%i<1and f(n/i,a+i*u,u*10)or f(n,a,u,i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzNCoMwEITveYq9FNSu1I1/jZgnKT2kiHShXUUM2KdP18PMwPfBrL/9vYhNafaf8H1NAQSDrzB6QvZukNEGmbIAywaUL1uZ8Wh1QS48kiqYM7kxhisXEWNB1SmVYcCIXFKeZgUHsMCDEGoEajWVxtZN2/V3p9QiNGeRdd1zMLBuLLveHHkiY01tGtOazvR/)

Just because there's no Python answer yet. It's really painful to lack implicit type conversion between string and int.